# How to find the "Assume Role Sign-In URL" Using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I need to be able to programmatically get the Sign-In URL for a role.

In boto (v2), there was a way to get an IAM role's "Sign-In URL" using `boto_iam_connection.get_signin_url()`. However, I have been unable to find something similar in boto3. I have searched through the STS client and IAM client methods, but there doesn't appear to be a way to do this.

I can see that this is exposed in the HTML of the AWS Console as `role.switchRoleLink`, but I don't find any references to this in boto3 either.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You can probably implement it yourself. https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/iam/connection.py#L1021

Comment: @jellycsc, I did implement this (with quite a few changes from the boto example you present), but I'm hoping that someone knows an SDK-native solution.